# How to stop an infinite consumer in a java project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to stop my consumer from running infinitely and also change topic name and group id in a loop and run my consumer. How can I proceed to do this?

I was experimenting if I could use currentLag() function and compare the difference between current offset and endoffset and make the consumer exit if the difference were to be zero but I couldn't succeed.